# How to prevent redirect to report when click on dashbaord tile via power bi workspace app?

Tags: powerbi

I have report and couple of tiles are pinned to dashboard.

I have edited the dashboard tile hyperlink to prevent the redirection to the report (using #). This prevents redirection to report when the dashbaord tile is clicked. This works fine when dashbaord is opened via the dashboard url.

However when I am on the same dashbaord via the power bi app, then on click of tile redirects me to original dashboard page outside of the app. How can I prevent the clicking of tile on dashboard in an app?